# Check if a value is in a list of columns in a pandas.DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with some data that looks like this (simplified) in a pandas.DataFrame:

```
|-----------|-----------|-----------|
| Feature 1 | Feature 2 | Feature 3 |
|-----------|-----------|-----------|
|     A     |     B     |     D     |
|     A     |     A     |     B     |
|     A     |     D     |     A     |
|     A     |     B     |     A     |
|     A     |     A     |     A     |
|     A     |     A     |     D     |
|-----------|-----------|-----------|
```

And I want to create a new column that answer to the question "Is the value 'D' present in any of the columns?"

So the final data would look like:

```
|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
| Feature 1 | Feature 2 | Feature 3 | Feature 4 |
|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
|     A     |     B     |     D     |    True   |
|     A     |     A     |     B     |   False   |
|     A     |     D     |     A     |    True   |
|     A     |     B     |     A     |   False   |
|     A     |     A     |     A     |   False   |
|     A     |     A     |     D     |    True   |
|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
```

I've tried using df.isin() method, but I'm still not able to this.

Do you guys know how to do this?

Answer (score 4):

try this approach:

```
df[df=='D'].any(1)
```

Comment: @jezrael, yes, `df.eq('D').any(1)` would be enough, but it's already covered by your answer... ;)

Answer (score 3):

You need simply compare `df` with `D` and then check at least one `True` by [`any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html):

```
df['Feature 4'] = (df == 'D').any(axis=1)
print (df)
  Feature 1 Feature 2 Feature 3 Feature 4
0         A         B         D      True
1         A         A         B     False
2         A         D         A      True
3         A         B         A     False
4         A         A         A     False
5         A         A         D      True
```

Or for comparing use [`eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html):

```
df['Feature 4'] = df.eq('D').any(axis=1)
print (df)
  Feature 1 Feature 2 Feature 3 Feature 4
0         A         B         D      True
1         A         A         B     False
2         A         D         A      True
3         A         B         A     False
4         A         A         A     False
5         A         A         D      True
```

---

```
print (df.eq('D'))
  Feature 1 Feature 2 Feature 3
0     False     False      True
1     False     False     False
2     False      True     False
3     False     False     False
4     False     False     False
5     False     False      True
```

Answer (score 0):

To help anyone having the same challange, I throw in another option.
You can use the `numpy where` function with or to check all the columns.

See a mockup below:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

a = [
['A', 'B', 'D'], 
['A','A', 'B'],
['A','D', 'A'],
['A','B', 'A'],
['A','A', 'A'],
['A','A', 'D']
]
df = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=['Feature 1', 'Feature 2', 'Feature 3'])
df['Feature 4'] = np.where((df['Feature 1']=='D') | (df['Feature 2']=='D') |(df['Feature 3']=='D') , True, False)
df
```

Results below:

```
+---+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|   | Feature 1 | Feature 2 | Feature 3 | Feature 4 |
+---+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| 0 | A         | B         | D         | True      |
+---+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| 1 | A         | A         | B         | False     |
+---+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| 2 | A         | D         | A         | True      |
+---+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| 3 | A         | B         | A         | False     |
+---+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| 4 | A         | A         | A         | False     |
+---+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| 5 | A         | A         | D         | True      |
+---+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```